# Pros and Cons of using Webmatrix.Database Helper in MVC Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, webmatrix

What are the Pros and Cons of using WebMatrix Database Helper by installing its Nuget Package and using raw SQL Queries in MVC Applications.

Sub-Points in the question is

1) Comparison between Performance Degradation(if any) vs enhanced productivity in using Helpers in MVC. Pros & Cons

2) Corner Cases like when Performance Bottleneck will happen

3) Scaling Application to millions of users.

I am personally more comfortable with raw SQL queries over Entity Framework as it gives me more control and using Database Helpers helps me getting the projects done faster so higher productivity while not worrying about underlying things as with time even Microsoft is also enhancing the Helpers Library & underlying architecture giving me best of both worlds & allows me to focus on things like adding better features, enhancing the UI/UX etc.
I tried to be as expressive & to the point as possible, still any improvement will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Database` helper is a simple wrapper around ADO.NET. As such, in theory it should be more performant than using Entity Framework (assuming your queries are well written) but the main downside is that the result of `Database` helper methods are dynamic types which are resolved at run time, so you lose compile time type checking. You could write your own extensions that project query results to strong types, and there are some libraries already out there that might help like [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) or [WebMatrix.Data.StronglyTyped](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/WebMatrix.Data.StronglyTyped)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will be keeping this thing in my mind